# Django admin: how to pass top bar notification

Tags: django, django-admin

When you save something via django admin you will get this bootstrap alert bar at the top of your page saying "save" or "please correct errors". How do I pass something in get/post parameters to be displayed in such bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for Django's [Messaging Framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/messages/).

Here's some code from the docs:

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Hello world.')
# Shortcut methods
messages.debug(request, '%s SQL statements were executed.' % count)
messages.info(request, 'Three credits remain in your account.')
messages.success(request, 'Profile details updated.')
messages.warning(request, 'Your account expires in three days.')
messages.error(request, 'Document deleted.')
```